# Enabling asp.net txtbox from button OnClientClick js function

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net

I want to enable a textBox and make it Visible (default settings are false for both) on button click. I can postback but it's inefficient so I want my button to activate onClientClick just to activate and make it Visible.

I tried this:

```
JS:
function EnableTxt() {
       document.getElementById( '<%=txtSearch.ClientID%>' ).disabled = 'false';
   }
```

```
HTML:
<asp:ImageButton ID="btnSearch2" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/search.png" Height="27px" Width="30px" ImageAlign="AbsBottom" OnClientClick="EnableTxt()"/>

<asp:TextBox ID="txtSearch" runat="server" CssClass="btnSearchStyle" Height="27px" Width="134px" onkeypress="return EnterEvent(event)" BackColor="#BDC3C7" BorderStyle="None" Visible="true" Enabled="false"></asp:TextBox>
```

The JS function that I found doesn't do anything...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code to-

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="btnSearch2" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/search.png" Height="27px" Width="30px" ImageAlign="AbsBottom" OnClientClick="if(!EnableTxt()){return false};"/>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtSearch" runat="server" CssClass="btnSearchStyle" Height="27px" Width="134px" onkeypress="return EnterEvent(event)"  BorderStyle="None" style="visibility:hidden" BackColor="#BDC3C7" Enabled="false"></asp:TextBox>
```

And change JS as-

```
 function EnableTxt()
  {
 var id = document.getElementById('<%=txtSearch.ClientID%>');
    if (id.style.visibility === "hidden" && id.getAttribute('disabled'))
    {
         id.style.visibility = "visible";
         id.removeAttribute("disabled");
    }
    else {
         id.style.visibility = "hidden";
         id.setAttribute("disabled");
         }
  }
```

Comment: Thank you!! Do you know how can I make it invisible with second press?

Comment: I have edited the code. Just change the JS function to toggle between show and hide. You can up-vote the answer if you found it helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

change in js, just remove the disabled attribute:

```
document.getElementById('<%=txtSearch.ClientID%>').removeAttribute("disabled");
```